# How does the "tag" attribute in router-link work?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I have these two `router-links`, one enclosed in a `li` element, the other applied with a `tag="li"` property:

```
<router-link tag="li" :to="{ name: 'work'}">Work</router-link
<li><router-link :to="{ name: 'news'}">News</router-link></li>
```

which a compiled in the browser like so:

[image]

Is the `tag` property of `router-link` designed to replace `html elements`? Will both links be recognized by browsers (SEO etc.) the same way? I'd like to shorten my `html` with the `tag` property but don't know if I should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tag` attribute [does not exist](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/index.html#removal-of-event-and-tag-props-in-router-link) in Vue Router 4 (which is currently only version of router you can use with Vue 3)

It was meant as an option to replace `a` with something different. However as `li` can not have `href` attribute, enclosing `<a>` inside `<li>` is your best option

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Vue without SSR (server side rendering) then there is no need to think about it.

And I found some information about it
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#removal-of-event-and-tag-props-in-router-link

I think they are just wrappers that's why removed and said use slots.